# How to pass value to the (function ( ) { })();when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input type hidden that contain a value 2

```
<input type="hidden" id="asd" value="2"/>
```

I need the value 2 so I am using following way

```
(function () {
   var div = $('#asd').val(); 
})();
```

but I get the value undefined how to solve it?

Comment: Wrap code in `ready()` callback or move the `<script>` to the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: You should either execute your code at the bottom of page or in a `document ready` handler. That means, when the rest of your DOM (including your hidden field) has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    var div = $('#asd').val(); 
});
```

So your function will be executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

**See a working example:**

```js
$(function() {
  var div = $('#asd').val();

  console.log(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="asd" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it is a good habit to put all of your code inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

because that prevent your code to begin before the rest of your DOM has been loaded.

So in your case your code should look like :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var div = $('#asd').val(); 
});
```

Comment: i put all code inside $( document ).ready(function() { still i get undefined

Comment: Have you jQuery included in your file?